# Startup.cs migration from .net core 2.2 to .net core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am migrating a .net core project to version 3.1, but I'm confused with this part of the startup.cs file:

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(opt =>
{
    opt.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
});

services.AddMvc(opt =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .Build();
        
    opt.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
    opt.Filters.Add<ModelStateValidationFilter>();
    //opt.Filters.Add<DbContextTransactionFilter>(); 
    opt.Filters.Add<ExceptionsFilter>();
})       
    .AddFluentValidation(opt => opt.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<Business.Exceptions.NotFoundException>());
```

should I keep the addMvc()?

With this, I am getting a 500 internal server error.

Comment: Please share the exception you got with 500 error

Comment: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.ExceptionContext.Exception.get returned {"Handler was not found for request of type MediatR.IRequestHandler System.InvalidOperationException

Comment: Well, it seems like you haven't register proper request handler for Mediatr and as far as I know it's not related to `AddMvc` at all

Comment: Everything was working fine before i did the migration

Answer (score 1):

`AddControllers` or `AddControllersWithViews` has replaced `AddMvc` in .NET Core 3

Quite a lot has changed in v3 so it would be good to review the migration guides.

[Migration guide for v2 to v3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30)

[Docs example of changed Startup.cs in v3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30#startup-changes)

If your error message is

```
Handler was not found for request of type MediatR.IRequestHandler System.InvalidOperationException
```

You can use MediatR's `MediatR.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection` package which includes a `.AddMediatR()` extension method, allowing you to register all handlers and pre/post-processors in a given assembly.

It will search the assembly for any Handlers, Profiles etc and register them for use.

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  // ...

  // Adds all MediatR handlers from the Assembly containing Startup
  services.AddMediatR(typeof(Startup));
}
```

[MediatR Docs](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/wiki)